# GetElementByID Dynamic php ID to js function call

Tags: php, getelementbyid, jscript

Could anybody help me with this little issue. Im trying to change the class of a page number if clicked. but im trying through a js function call using a dynamic php ID . The code below should show you what i mean, Basically the function would change the class of the selected number.

```
echo"
 <div class='pagebuttonsdiv'>";
     for ( $x =0 ; $x < $pagesnum ; $x++ ) {   
         $pagex=$x+1;
         if ($pagex<1) {$pagex==1;} 
         if ($pagex>$pagesnum) {$pagex==$pagesnum;};
         if ($x > $pagesnum) {$x==$pagesnum;}

        echo "
        <div id='{$x}' class='pagebuttons' onclick='pageclick({$x},
        {$display}, {$maxresults} , {$startfrom});'>
        {$pagex}</div>";

                if ($x==$ifclicked) {?>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                           document.getElementById({$x}).className = 
                           'pagebuttonsclicked';}
                    </script>
                    <?php 
                };

     };

echo"
</div>
";
```

Anybody have any idea how i should go about this, Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems a bit confusing what you have, where is $ifclicked defined? And where is your pageclick() method defined? I think you are mixing php and js execution a bit here...

Comment: $Ifclicked is simply defined by the onclick of the div in the js function - $ifclicked = {$x}->the number clicked... the other variables   are for other posts.... in this function...  
                                                                                                         
 function pageclick(pagex , display , maxresults , startfrom){

var startfrom=pagex*display

document.getElementById('startpoint').value =(startfrom);
document.getElementById('pagecurrent').value =(pagex);
document.getElementById('pagechange').submit(); return false; 
}

Comment: Please add that to your question, formatted. Also, $ifclicked is inside a PHP block, which happens long before any javascript executes. You will either need AJAX, or to restructure a bit what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <div id="id[<?php echo $x; ?>]" class="pagebuttons" onclick="pageclick(<?php echo$x; ?>)">
    {$pagex}</div>
```

Not sure why are you sending all those variables in function. you just need the id to change that.

Comment: <script>function pageclick(i){
     document.getElementById("id[" + i + "]").className = 
     "pagebuttonsclicked";}                

    </script>

Comment: I wish for the clicked page number to be highlighted after click also. so it stays clicked. but onclick only changes the class until POST , then the number is back to normal... so i cannot see what page i have clicked....

Comment: ofcourse it wont stand that class. because javascript you're using is for that page only. if your click is going to next page or reloading the same page with php or some other language. you should use the id to be highlited(with that class) if on the same page. with GET or POST method. if it's going to an entire new page just give the class to that specific id yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Answer -

```
        echo"

          ";
for ( $x =0 ; $x < $pagesnum ; $x++ ) {   

         $pagex=$x+1;
         if ($pagex<1) {$pagex==1;} 
         if ($pagex>$pagesnum) {$pagex==$pagesnum;};
         if ($x > $pagesnum) {$x==$pagesnum;}


        echo "

        <div id='{$x}' class='pagebuttons' onclick='pageclick({$x},{$display}, {$maxresults} , {$startfrom});'>
        {$pagex}</div>";

            if ($x==$ifclicked) { echo " <script> document.getElementById({$x}).className='pagebuttonsclicked' </script> ";};  


};


    echo"
    </div>

    <br>

    ";
```

call the function from php to change class. = onlclicking the number, it changes its class to change whatever you wish it to change according to the new css class... I changed the border surround color...